# Cassandra mutation stages are increasing on only one node even though the data model looks fine

Tags: cassandra

We have built cassandra cluster with 6 Nodes, each one has 64G RAM and 16 Cores. We have used Replication Factor of 3.

We have allocated heap of 8G.

When we ingest the data from spark, one of the node is having high number of mutation stages pending and some of the mutations are getting dropped.

1) The machine is same configuration as others. 
2) It does not have any other jobs running.

We do not have and hotspots as far as i know.

We are loading to two tables based on access pattern. One of the table has 28 columns and other has 9 columns.

The problems are occurring to table with 28 columns. 
We have reduced the concurrent.writes configuration to 2, so that there wont be too much load pushed to node. Even that did not resolve the issue.

Are we missing any thing.?

Comment: What are your schemas? How do you know you don't have hotspots?

Comment: The data has enough randomness but hw can we confirm we have hotspots.? The data is production data and partition key selected is a composite of two columns

Comment: Also are you using vnodes?

Comment: No. I havent set any initial tokens. We are using 3.9 version of cassandra

Comment: Hi Russ, other than having knowledge of partition key, can i use any metrics  to identify the hotspots.?

Comment: Well typically one node being overloaded is a sign :) But you should probably use spark to see if any partition keys are being hit especially hard, groupCount(PartitionKey) or something.